# How to 'spread jam' effect using geometry nodes?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I am trying to simulate jam being spread across a burger bun. I want to use geometry nodes to do this. The end result will look like this:
[image]
And I want to appear on the bun like it's being spread (I will animate a knife later). I have tried to use a curve to do this, along with the trim curve node. But it was a headache getting the result I wanted. Then I tried to use a proximity node to delete geometry, but the result came out all jagged. My thought is that I should somehow scale the geometry from one end to another. Is there a simple way to do this?
Here's an annotated picture to illustrate the movement of the animation:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The relevant part is the framed one below, as the other aspects can be linked to your actual jam model.

[image]

The idea is to delete geometry where for all that is in front of the knife with a little random variation around it.

For the upper part of the node tree (a subdivided plane) I think that could be you model instead, if subdivided a bit.

[image]